# Simulating Inter Thread Communication in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a singleton instance which i am getting in my two threads, one thread, i.e, AddEmployeeInfo is adding the employee details into ArrayList and notifies the other thread, i.e., DisplayEmployeeInfo which displays all the employee information which are added and then waits for further data,
please help me with what changes should i include to make it work and proper inter thread communication is being done :

```
class AddEmployeeInfo implements Runnable{
SingletonInstance inst;
public AddEmployeeInfo(SingletonInstance instance) {
inst = instance;
}
 @Override
   public void run() {
Employee e1 = new Employee();
 e1.setEmpId(001);
 e1.setEmpName("SK");
e1.setEmpExp(2);
inst.addEmployee(e1);

  Employee e2 = new Employee();
  e2.setEmpId(002);
  e2.setEmpName("AMIT");
   e2.setEmpExp(3);
   inst.addEmployee(e2);
    } 
  }
 class DisplayEmployeeInfo implements Runnable{
    SingletonInstance inst;
  public DisplayEmployeeInfo(SingletonInstance instance) {
 inst = instance;
  }
  @Override
   public void run() {
   while(true){
   inst.displayEmployeeInfo();
     }}}
    public class EmployeeInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SingletonInstance instance = new SingletonInstance();
       Thread t1 = new Thread(new AddEmployeeInfo(instance));
      Thread t2 = new Thread(new DisplayEmployeeInfo(instance));
        t1.start();
         t2.start();
         }
         }
        class SingletonInstance{
            public List<Employee> empDetails = new ArrayList<>();
             boolean flag = false;

             public synchronized void addEmployee(Employee emp){
          if (flag) {
           try {
             wait();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
              }
             }
          flag = true;
             notify();
            empDetails.add(emp);
              }
             public synchronized void displayEmployeeInfo() {
           if (!flag) {
              try {
              wait();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
               }

           for(Employee getDetails : empDetails){
           System.out.println(getDetails.getEmpId() + " " +                 getDetails.getEmpName()); 
               }
             flag = false;
             notify();
           }
             }
```

Comment: Your singleton model is implemented incorrectly (or at least dangerously), there is no synchornisation around the creation of the single instance, allowing multiple instances to be created by multiple threads. Convention would suggest an `enum` is the simplest choice for setting this up

Comment: I don't see thread communication mechanisms, perhaps you should consider having a look at [thread locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) and/or blockig queues

Comment: can you please suggest the correct solution for this.thanks.

Comment: Yes, but it would be better if you did some due-diligence and research into the problem, starting with the link I've already provided, you'll better understand the issues and various possible solutions which are available to you - as there's not just one solution

Comment: Re, "the other thread [...] displays all the employee information [...] and then waits for further data."  That is not what you have implemented.  There's no place where the "display" thread waits for anything.  In order to wait, it must call `Object.wait()` or call some other _blocking_ method.  The tutorial that MadProgrammer linked to can tell you more about that subject.  Also, you might want the "add" thread to call some blocking method too.  The way it's written, it looks like it will quickly use up all your heap space.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i have created the code, have a look and  someone let me know in case of any improvement further, i have added the code in the main question i asked.